# Android TextView strange text alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, text-alignment

In many different questions the answer to align the text inside a TextView was either: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or to set the `gravity` or `textAlignment` however none of these options seemed to work on my emulator. I don't have the preview since it's code generated text.
Using my current layout I get this in my emulator:
[image]
Why does the black text behave in such a strange way? I want to left align it. This is my current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.domain.citytour.activity.ImpressumActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/locationTitle"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:id="@+id/locationContent"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm sorry to bother this comunity again with this question.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with your "code generated text".

Comment: I agree, cause I've tested your code in a mini project without any alteration and the text was left aligned

Comment: I kind of expected that answer :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:text="Left Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"/>
```

Here's a similar question:
[Android TextView Align text to Right and Left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724975/android-textview-align-text-to-right-and-left)

Comment: `android:gravity="left"` use this one instead.

Comment: Nope, nothing new