# Android TextView Align text to Left and Right

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have a `TextView` that has two texts, one aligned at the left side of the `TextView` and one at the right side of the `TextView`.

I referred this [[Android TextView Align text to Right and Left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724975/android-textview-align-text-to-right-and-left/45309543#45309543]) (@daemontus) for setting the text.

But how do add a text if I enter the text at right side of the `TextView` first and then left side of the `TextView`

1) Input: Enter Button 1 to display Text1

[image]

2) Output: Enter Button 2 to display Text2 along with Text1

[image]

```
public void setLeftRightText(TextView view, String left, String right,Enum keysel) {
if(keysel == RSK_KEY) {
        SpannableString merged=new SpannableString(left + "\n" + right);
        merged.setSpan(
                new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL),
                0, left.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );
        merged.setSpan(
                new LineOverlapSpan(),
                left.length(), left.length() + 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );
        merged.setSpan(
                new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),
                left.length() + 1, left.length() + 1 + right.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );
        view.setText(merged);
    }
    else if (keysel == LSK_KEY){
        final String resultText = right + "  " + left;
        final SpannableString styledResultText = new SpannableString(resultText);
        styledResultText.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE )), left.length() + 2, left.length() + 2 +right.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        styledResultText.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL )), 0, left.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        view.setText(styledResultText);

    }

}
```

**LineOverlapSpan.java**

```
public class LineOverlapSpan implements LineHeightSpan {

    public void chooseHeight(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int end, final int spanstartv, final int v, final Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        fm.bottom += fm.top;
        fm.descent += fm.top;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your snippet of code.

Comment: For that you have to create a custom view and draw the text yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result in a single text view. Create a view that extends text view and override the `onDraw`

I've put together a small example. Hope it will give you an idea at-least

```
public class LeftRightTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private String mLeftText, mRightText;

    public LeftRightTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public LeftRightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public void setLeftText(String leftText) {
        mLeftText = leftText;
        setText(mLeftText);
    }

    public void setRightText(String rightText) {
        mRightText = rightText;
        invalidate();
    }

    public LeftRightTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LeftRightTextView, defStyleAttr, 0);
        mLeftText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.LeftRightTextView_lr_left_text);
        mRightText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.LeftRightTextView_lr_right_text);
        typedArray.recycle();
        setText(mLeftText);
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //let it draw the left text as usual
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Now draw the right text
        int rightEnd = getWidth() - getPaddingRight();
        float textWidth = mTextPaint.measureText(mRightText);
        canvas.drawText(mRightText, rightEnd - textWidth, mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().descent - mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().ascent, mTextPaint);

    }
}
```

And the attributes

```
<declare-styleable name="LeftRightTextView">
    <attr name="lr_left_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="lr_right_text" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

In layout

```
<me.srs.myapplication.LeftRightTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lr_left_text="Hello"
    app:lr_right_text="World"/>
```

And this is the result

[image: The result in layout preview]

Comment: I dont want the strings to be hardcoded (lr_left_text and lr_right_text). I'm gettin the left and right strings from the text view for example: String getText_lsk1 =(String) mytxtvw2.getText();

Comment: MainActivity.java:`public void onClick(View view) { if (view.getId() == R.id.mybtn52) { drawLine("",mytxtvw2, drawcolor.WHITE_COLOR, 28); } else if (view.getId() == R.id.mybtnlsk1) { mytxtvw1_lsk1.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR); String getText_lsk1 =(String) mytxtvw2.getText(); String getText_rsk1 =(String) mytxtvw1_lsk1.getText(); setLeftRightText(mytxtvw1_lsk1, getText_rsk1, getText_lsk1,LSK_KEY);'I'm calling setLeftRightText function which should align the text to the left&right of the TextView

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... Thanks

Comment: You can set the font size before you draw the text on the canvas

Answer (score 0):

You need to take two separate textviews to achieve your requirements.

Please use following code and check.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:text="Left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I dont want the strings to be hardcoded (lr_left_text and lr_right_text). I'm gettin the left and right strings from the text view for example:    String getText_lsk1 =(String) mytxtvw2.getText();

Comment: You don't have to put hardcoded text, this is only for demo, so you can set your own text from API or from response or from local database and so.

Comment: **MainActivity.java**:`public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.mybtn52) {
            drawLine("",mytxtvw2, drawcolor.WHITE_COLOR, 28);
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.mybtnlsk1) {
            mytxtvw1_lsk1.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR);
            String getText_lsk1 =(String) mytxtvw2.getText();
            String getText_rsk1 =(String) mytxtvw1_lsk1.getText(); setLeftRightText(mytxtvw1_lsk1, getText_rsk1, getText_lsk1,LSK_KEY);'I'm calling setLeftRightText function which should align the text to the left&right of the TextView.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a custom view and override onDraw method of same , to achieve desired functionality.